# regex: \w EXCEPT underscore (add to class and then exclude from class)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

This question applies to Python 3 regular expressions. I think it might apply to other languages as well.

The question could easily be misunderstood so I'll be careful in describing it.

As background, `\w` means "a word character." In certain circumstances Python 3 will treat this as just `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` but if the regular expression is a string, it will be Unicode-aware so that `\w` means "any Unicode word character." This is generally a good thing as people use different languages, and it would be hard to construct a range like `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` for all languages at once. I think `\w` is therefore most useful in a multilingual setting.

But there is a problem: What if you don't want to match underscores because you don't think they're really a word character (for your particular application)?

If you're only focused on English applications, the best solution is probably to skip `\w` entirely and just use `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. But if you're focused on global applications and you don't want underscores, it seems like you might be in a really unfortunate situation. I haven't done it, but I assume it would be really tough to write a range that represents 100 languages at once just so you can avoid that underscore.

So my question is: Is there any way to use `\w` to match any Unicode word character, but somehow also exclude underscores (or some other undesirable character) from the class? I don't think I've seen anything like this described, but it would be highly useful. Something like `[\w^_]`. Of course that won't actually work, but what I mean is "use a character class that starts with everything represented by `\w`, but then go ahead and remove underscores from that class."

Thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have two options.

1. `[^\W_]`

   This is very effective and does exactly what you want. It's also straightforward.
2. With [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/): `[[\w]--[_]]`, note you need "V1" flag set, so you need

   ```
   r = regex.compile(r"(?V1)[\w--_]")
   ```

   or

   ```
   r = regex.compile(r"[\w--_]", flags=regex.V1)
   ```

   This looks better (readability) IMO if you're familiar with Matthew Barnett's `regex` module, which is more powerful than Python's stock `re`.

Comment: Oh wow, #1 is genius, I had never thought about that before. Not familiar with the regex module but I'll give it a look. Thanks!